# Load image from URL into a TImage

Tags: delphi, get, indy, timage

I'm trying to get images from the Internet and present them in my application inside a `TImage`.

I found a solution that works for URLs with HTTP, but not for HTTPS:

```
var
  MS : TMemoryStream;
  GIf: TGIFImage;
  IdHTTP1 : tIdHTTP;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  GIf := TGIFImage.Create;
  IdHTTP1 := tIdHTTP.Create(NIL);
  try
    IdHTTP1.get('http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif',MS);
    Ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
    Gif.LoadFromStream(MS);
    IMAGE1.Picture.Assign(GIF);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(GIF);
    FreeAndNil(MS);
  end;
end;
```

When trying to get a URL with HTTPS, the following exception is raised:

> IOHandler value is not valid

Are there any changes to this solution to make it work with HTTPS?

Comment: You have to set up SSL for your TidHTTP client. There are many existing posts here about doing so. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D%5Bindy%5D+idhttp+ssl

Comment: What version of Delphi/Indy are you using? TIdHTTP has been able to [use HTTPS without configuration](https://www.indyproject.org/2014/12/22/new-https-functionality-for-tidhttp/) for a decade now. That being said, the default SSLIOHandler is [set to TLS 1.0 by default](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/181), so you should configure it explicitly to enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2.

Comment: There are also various alternatives provided by Windows to simply download a file such as [InternetOpenUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetopenurlw) (WinINet library), [URLOpenBlockingStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775127(v=vs.85)) (URLMon library) and [WinHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/about-winhttp) library.